# multi module maven project module expose as soap web service

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, soap, module

I have a multi module maven-spring project. Following is the structure-

```
ParentService
---ChildService-service
---ChildService-core
---ChildService-web
---ChildService-wsClient
---ChildService-mongo
```

I have created a new module called ChildService-wsService where I will write methods and expose as Axis2 SOAP web service. I have been able to write independent methods in classes of this module project and expose as service but I want to call methods of ChildService-service module.

When I try to call methods of ChildService-service module it gives me errors like NoClassDefFoundError.

Following is sample code--

```
public class HelloWorld  {
@Autowired
private  ITestService iTestService;
@Autowired
ICommonService commonService;



public String getVal(String s){
    return s+"...testing...";
}

public String getValFfmService(){
    iTestService=new TestServiceImpl();
    return iTestService.test();

}
```

I am getting error as following--

```
Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/service/test/business/ITestService at java.lang.Class.forName0
```

If I include following line in class then also I am getting classnotfound error.

```
extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your other projects that you need as dependencies, for instance, in your pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>ChildService-service</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    ...
</dependencies>
```

Then you need to install these dependencies in your local repository (`mvn clean install` will do it), or, in Eclipse, you need to activate `Workspace resolution` (right click on your module, Maven > Enable Workspace Resolution).

Comment: Thanks! I have added that. Following is my pom--    `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sahaj.portal</groupId>
   <artifactId>ChildService-core</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sahaj.portal</groupId>
   <artifactId>ChildService-service</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: You also need to do a Maven update in Eclipse after installing in local repository (right click, Maven > Update Project; check the field `Force Update of Snapshots/Releases`). Does it work?

Comment: Getting following error    Servlet AxisAdminServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport from [Module "deployment.ChildService-wsServiceEAR.ear.ChildService-wsService.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Comment: Failed to define class com.test.HelloWorld in Module "deployment.ChildService-wsServiceEAR.ear.ChildService-wsService.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/test/HelloWorld (Module "deployment.ChildService-wsServiceEAR.ear.ChildService-wsService.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

Comment: Hmm, are they Services that are automatically loaded using the `ServiceLoader` mechanism?

Comment: except pom.xml do i need to have any other xml?

Comment: Well, if you expect a Service to be automatically loaded by the `ServiceLoader`, you need to provide a file in `META-INF/services`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html. But is it your situation?

Comment: right now I am unable to refer my other modules at runtime. Though at complile time I am getting access to them.

Comment: So it is just a matter of building a fat JAR, or properly generating your WAR, or properly referencing path to your libraries in command line. This is a different question.

Comment: When I try to extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport then I am getting Servlet AxisAdminServlet threw load() exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: OK, but you don't have any compilation errors anymore, right? Then my answer fixed your issue of not declaring modules in your pom.xml. Getting some code to correctly use dependencies at runtime is a different question (fat jar, or WAR packaging, or providing path to libraries)

Comment: in pom.xml entries were present before. As per your advices I did mvn clean install.

Comment: Ok OK, sorry, I thought you had compilation errors. So, I'm pretty sure you need to tell the `Service Module Loader` how to load your components. It has to be the same principle as for the standard `Service Loader`. This can be difficult inside a servlet container, and you might need to load your components "manually" in your code. Does this help?